# Apache 2.2, Django, use Python 3.5

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I want to run django with apache2.2 and python 3.6, after making changes in wsgy.py and virtuahost still running python 2.6

Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.9 configured -- resuming normal operations

Here wsgi.py

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/home/app/myapp/sivale')
sys.path.append('/home/app/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And here

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName nuevo.sivale.mx
Alias /static /home/app/myapp/static
<Directory /home/app/myapp/static>
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/app/myapp/myapp>
    <Files wsgi.py>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess sivale python-path=/home/app/myapp:/home/app/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup sivale
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/app/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py


</VirtualHost>
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

Comment: Did you restart the apache server after the changes to the configuration?

Comment: Yes, every time i make a change i restart the server

Answer (score 0):

It seems `WSGIPythonHome` is missing from your configuration. According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) if you are not using the default `python` interpreter of your system you should add this explicitly.

Since your default is python 2.6 (based on your question it seems you have kept it), it is the one being used.

Answer (score 0):

If your mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 2.6 as your log messages shows, you cannot force it to use a Python virtual environment created for Python 3.6. A installation of mod_wsgi will only work for the version of Python it was compiled for.

What you will need to do is uninstall the mod_wsgi system package and install mod_wsgi yourself from source code compiled against Python 3.6. There is no way around doing it. You cannot use `WSGIPythonHome` or `python-home` option of `WSGIDaemonProcess` to force it to use a different Python installation.

Installing mod_wsgi from source code is also recommended in your case purely because mod_wsgi 3.2 is ancient and is not supported.